# Check regex result in a list ,if-else python

Tags: python, regex, list, if-statement

I have a list of words (even 2 or 3 words in 1 object) . I have compiled a regex to match any of the words in the list to a random string . If it matches , that object of the list is returned ,else it will execute another regex on the string to return an expression.
my code:
"layouts" is the list of words and "layout_re" uses the words in list to match in the string "str". If ms is present in list , return ms as it is otherwise use expression of `p` to return the pattern.

```
def layout_corr(str):

    ms = layout_re.search(str)
    if ms in layouts:
       ms=ms

    else:
       p = re.compile(r'(?:\w+\s+){1,2}layout')
       ms = re.findall(p,str)
    return ms
```

The output i get is that of the `else` statement .
eg:- `str = " no  804  8th main 2nd c cross hrbr layout 1st block"`
the list contains "hrbr layout" hence hrbr layout must be returned. But instead , the function returns `"cross hrbr layout"` which is the ms calculated by `else` statement.. What is the problem with the `if` statement??

Comment: `re.search` returns a `match` object (or `None`), while `re.findall` returns a `list`. Neither one returns purely object matched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`re.search` returns a match object, not a string, so that:

```
ms in layouts
```

will always return false. Use this instead:

```
def layout_corr(str):
    ms = layout_re.search(str)
    if ms:
       return ms.group()    
    else:
       p = re.compile(r'((?:\w+\s+){1,2})layout')
       ms = re.findall(p,str)
       return ms
```

Comment: You could use `(\w+(?:\s+\w+)?)\s+layout` for the second regex, if you want to trim spaces.

Comment: Also, you should avoid using `str` since it's a function name (already told you in chat, but mentioning it here too)

Answer (score 0):

1) change `ms=ms` to `return ms`

2) In order to "catch" the string `"hrbr layout"` - change the line:

```
p = re.compile(r'(?:\w+\s+){1,2}layout')
```

to:

```
p = re.compile(r' (\w+? layout)')
```

Demo:

```
p = re.compile(r' (\w+? layout)')
ms = re.findall(p,"no  804  8th main 2nd c cross hrbr layout 1st block")
print(ms[0]) // prints: "hrbr layout"
```

Comment: hrbr is in list. if i use this expression then it will extract 1 word before layout always.. what i want is to check presence in the list called"layouts" and return the same if present.. If not , then return 2 words before layout.. Hrbr is in the layouts list , so i want the 1 st statement to return the exprssion

Comment: @Sword in that case change `ms=ms` to `return ms`